# compilationWin32Exception when building Windows Store App in unity3D

Tags: c#, windows, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2017, hololens

Hello i am trying to build an windows store app in Unity3D(Unity 5.6.0f3). 
When following these steps:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/holograms_230

at the scanning step when you need to build the app i get the following 2 errors in unity:

==

```
Could not start compilationWin32Exception: ApplicationName='C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Tools\Roslyn\CoreRun.exe', CommandLine='"C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Tools\Roslyn\csc.exe" /noconfig @Temp/UnityTempFile-5ed7a9a146122744fb2017a810d85b49', CurrentDirectory=''
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_noshell (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo, System.Diagnostics.Process process)
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_common (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo, System.Diagnostics.Process process)
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start ()
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process:Start ()
UnityEditor.Utils.Program.Start (System.EventHandler exitCallback) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Utils/Program.cs:44)
UnityEditor.Utils.Program.Start () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Utils/Program.cs:28)
UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.MicrosoftCSharpCompiler.StartCompilerImpl (System.Collections.Generic.List`1 arguments, System.String argsPrefix) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Scripting/Compilers/MicrosoftCSharpCompiler.cs:168)
UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.MicrosoftCSharpCompiler.StartCompiler () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Scripting/Compilers/MicrosoftCSharpCompiler.cs:190)
UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.ScriptCompilerBase.BeginCompiling () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Scripting/Compilers/ScriptCompilerBase.cs:40)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

==

```
Error building Player because scripts have compile errors in the editor
```

==

Does somebody know the solution to this problem?

Comment: I believe System.Diagnostics.Process is not supported in .Net Core which is the backend when deploying to Hololens or any other WSA application.